# Is there a way to disable Internet acces for all but one program?

Tags: windows, firewall

There's a student in our school that needs Farsi translation for his finals. The school bought Babylon (from Babel) without checking for offline support for Farsi.

Now I need to find a way to disable all traffic but `Babylon.exe`. Do I need to find out the port and work with that, or is there some easy way to do this, like some sort of registry “magic”?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Windows Firewall already has program-based rules. Edit them via `wf.msc`:

1. Disable all outbound rules that are currently there (perhaps except for core features like DNS Client or Windows Update).
2. Add an outbound rule for `C:\Program Files [...]\Babylon.exe`.
3. In the firewall's general settings, set the outbound policy to "block by default".

However, once traffic leaves the computer, there is no longer any way to associate it reliably with a specific program. If you want to filter at network/router level, you *will* need to find out which hosts the program communicates with. (Most likely it'll use the generic HTTP port however.)

Comment: Be prepared for strange behavior from programs that are able to resolve their DNS requests but then cannot establish connections to their intended remote targets.